# magento block doesnt work

Tags: php, magento

My indexController.php

```
class Pfay_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function indexAction () {
    echo "hello world from indexController.php";
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
 <default>
      <reference name="content">
      </reference>
  </default>
  <routeurfrontend_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
            ITS WORK! <block type="core/template" template="test/afficher.phtml" /> 
            ITS DOESNT WORK! <block type="test/monblock" name="afficher_monbloc" template="test/afficher.phtml" />
       </reference>
  </routeurfrontend_index_index>
```

```
<h1>Template  afficher.phtml</h1>

<?php
echo "hello world from afficher php";
?>
```

when I use string

```
<block type="core/template" template="test/afficher.phtml" />
```

all work, and I see "hello from indexController.php" ,  header, footer and  other, and in center of page I see "Template  afficher.phtml" and "hello world from afficher php".

But when I try use my block I see ONLY "hello from indexController.php".

Monblock.php

```
<?php
 class Pfay_Test_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
   {
     public function methodblock()
        {
          return ‘informations about my block !!’ ;
       }
   }
```

Anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I use this site http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-create-block-44
and in this site he use wrong
     ‘informations about my block !!’ ;
I replace 
     "informations about my block !!" ;

And now its work!